# Trying to synchronize method within runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a ConcurrentMap that gets instantiated outside of my runnables, but shared and updated within / accross the runnables. My runnables need to be concurrent, but my concurrentMap update needs to be synchronized to prevent the replacement of previous entrys. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class ExecutionSubmitExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Ten concurrent threads
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Future<Example>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            Example example = new Example(concurrentMap, x);
            Future<Example> future = es.submit(example, example);
            tasks.add(future);
        }

        try {
            for (Future<Example> future : tasks) {
                Example e = future.get();
            }

            for (Entry<Integer,String> obj : concurrentMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key " + obj.getKey() + " " + obj.getValue());
            }
            es.shutdown();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

**Runnable**

```
public class Example implements Runnable {

    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap;
    private int thread;

    public Example(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap, int thread) {
        this.concurrentMap = concurrentMap;
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            runAnalysis(i);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void runAnalysis(int index) {
        if(concurrentMap.containsKey(index)) {
            System.out.println("contains integer " + index);
        } else {
            System.out.println("put " + index + " thread " + thread);
            concurrentMap.put(index, "thread " + thread);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results** - notice index 0 is added multiple times rather than once. It should be added by thread 0 and read as contained by thread 9. I somehow need to lock this method from the other threads until the update has been completed.

```
put 0 thread 0
put 0 thread 9
put 0 thread 6
put 0 thread 7
put 1 thread 7
put 0 thread 2
put 0 thread 1
put 0 thread 5
put 0 thread 3
put 0 thread 4
contains integer 1
contains integer 1
contains integer 1
contains integer 1
put 2 thread 7
put 1 thread 6
put 1 thread 9
put 1 thread 0
put 0 thread 8
contains integer 2
contains integer 2
contains integer 2
put 2 thread 2
put 2 thread 1
put 2 thread 5
put 2 thread 3
contains integer 1
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 2
key 0 thread 8
key 2 thread 3
key 1 thread 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`synchronized` on the method means `synchronized` on `this` object. Since you are creating new objects every time

```
Example example = new Example(concurrentMap, x);
```

The synchronization is happening on different objects, so nothing blocks.

You need to `synchronized` on a shared object or use a shared [`Lock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html). These can be passed to the `Example` object or you can use a `static` field [as suggested by Luiggi.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19773221/trying-to-synchronize-method-within-runnable/19773248#comment29388573_19773248) In this case, be careful that the field isn't synchronized on anywhere else or it may interfere with this execution.

Comment: Solution: use a `static final Object lock` to synchronize the method.

Comment: I assumed it was because I was synchronizing on multiple objects, I'm not sure I understand the implementation of Luiggi suggestion.

Comment: @George You create an `static Object` object so that it is available to all your `Example` instances. Instead of `synchronized` on the method, wrap the body of your method in a `synchronized(lock)` block.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I posted an answer in which I believe is the correct implementation. If you wouldn't mind verifying I'm doing this correctly, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solution based on Sotirios Delimanolis, Luiggi Mendoza, Sotirios Delimanolis answer.

main

```
public class ExecutionSubmitExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        List<Future<Example>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();

        ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            Example e = new Example(concurrentMap, x);
            Future<Example> future = es.submit(e, e);
            tasks.add(future);
        }
        // -- all threads should be launching, let's get the ExecutionSubmitExample objects



        try {
            for (Future<Example> future : tasks) {
                Example e = future.get();
            }

            for (Entry<Integer,String> obj : concurrentMap.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println("key " + obj.getKey() + " " + obj.getValue());
            }
            es.shutdown();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ie);
        }
    }
}
```

runnable

```
public class Example implements Runnable {

    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap;
    private int thread;
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public Example(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap, int thread) {
        this.concurrentMap = concurrentMap;
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            runAnalysis(i);
        }
    }

    public void runAnalysis(int index) {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if(concurrentMap.containsKey(index)) {
                System.out.println("contains integer " + index);
            } else {
                System.out.println("put " + index + " thread " + thread);
                concurrentMap.put(index, "thread " + thread);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

results

```
put 0 thread 0
contains integer 0
put 1 thread 7
put 2 thread 7
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
key 0 thread 0
key 2 thread 7
key 1 thread 7
```

Comment: You're synchronizing correctly. Note that `synchronized` is not well suited for ordering (as in first, second, third) execution. I don't know if that's how you intended to use it, but just FYI.

Comment: Order is of no relevance, in my real word code I'm just doing a database lookup of values and appending them to my ConcurrentMap. When I process a csv file, if the value doesn't exist in the ConcurrentMap, then I add it and persist it to the database so that it's available to other items in the csv. After a couple hundred rows are read, I commit the ConcurrentMap objects to the database making them available to the next days batch job. I'm only doing this to reduce database lookup values.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid synchronizing when using a ConcurrentMap.  It provides other methods for handling these types of operations.  For this case the putIfAbsent method should be preferred over a contains and then a put.

```
public void runAnalysis(int index) {
    if (concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(index, "thread " + thread) == null) {
        System.out.println("put " + index + " thread " + thread);
    } else {
        System.out.println("contains integer " + index);
    }
}
```

Comment: using putIfAbsent results in duplicate puts. Feel free to try it using the code provided in my answer. example put 0 thread 6
put 0 thread 0
put 0 thread 8
put 0 thread 2
put 0 thread 5
put 0 thread 9
put 0 thread 3
put 0 thread 1

Comment: @George putIfAbsent will not result in multiple puts.  If it did then there would be no point in the class.  I tried with the code you provided, and it behaves exactly how I'd expect.  I suspect that you implemented the putIfAbsent incorrectly in your test.

Comment: I think I found my issue, I was doing the following thinking putIfAbsent was just a condition check resulting in my failure.     public void runAnalysis(int index) {
        if (concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(index, "thread " + thread) == null) {
            System.out.println("contains integer " + index);
        } else {
            System.out.println("put " + index + " thread " + thread);
            concurrentMap.put(index, "thread " + thread);
        }
    }

Comment: @George Yeah, you had the bodies of the if and else statements reversed.

Comment: This is ultimately the best answer and the choice I'll use in production code, but do to my original question being about synchronized method, I can't mark this as the best answer. Thank you so much for the help. I like this much better.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a new class "RunAnalysis" and add the code of method runAnalysis() in that class like this:

```
class RunAnalysis {
    public synchronized void analyse(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap, int thread, int index) {
        if(concurrentMap.containsKey(index)) {
            System.out.println("contains integer " + index);
        } else {
            System.out.println("put " + index + " thread " + thread);
            concurrentMap.put(index, "thread " + thread);
        }
    }
}

public class SyncExample implements Runnable {
    RunAnalysis runAnalysis = new RunAnalysis();
    ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap;
    private int thread;

    public SyncExample(ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String> concurrentMap, int     thread) {
        this.concurrentMap = concurrentMap;
        this.thread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            runAnalysis.analyse(concurrentMap, thread, i);
        }
    }
}
```

then the output is:

```
put 0 thread 1
put 1 thread 1
put 2 thread 1
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
contains integer 0
contains integer 1
contains integer 2
key 0 thread 1
key 1 thread 1
key 2 thread 1
```